# Как отследить IP адреса маршрутизаторов через которые проходит запрос?

Tags: ip, маршрутизация, osi

При запросе на какой либо сервер он передается через несколько маршрутизаторов. Необходимо найти программу или дать идею как можно отследить IP адреса всех точек через которые проходит запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`traceroute` (`tracert` в Windows).

Идея — на адрес конечного сервера посылаются пакеты с увеличивающимся начиная с 1 TTL и ловятся посылаемые транзитными маршрутизаторами ICMP-сообщения "Time exceeded in-transit".

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а есть чтобы на карте обозначались эти точки. То есть чтобы в графическом виде посмотреть как идет запрос. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дикий вопрос :) зачем вам это? нанести по точкам ракетный удар? :) А вообще есть графическое представление мировой карты роутинга на основе bgp в ripn.

Comment: Увы, нет;) Хочу наглядно показать какой путь совершает запрос чтобы добраться до конечного узла

Comment: В общем случае задача нерешаема. Описанный в ответе метод, который использует traceroute, может давать неверные данные, поскольку любой маршрутизатор в цепи имеет право делать с TTL что захочет - уменьшить на 1 (дефолтное поведение), уменьшить на бОльшее значение (увеличение стоимости маршрутизации через себя для уменьшения загрузки, в трассе будет несколько копий узла), не изменять (тогда он вообще не виден в трассе), и даже увеличить ("усилитель")... А ещё он может просто не отправлять понги (тогда он тоже не виден в трассе, вернее, виден как не отвечающий узел с неизвестным адресом).

Comment: @Akina в общем — нет, но задача _достоверного_ узнавания не ставилась, а для удовлетворения простого любопытства в большинстве случаев этот метод всё ещё работает.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста что значит в общем. В каких случаях мы можем достоверно узнать по какому маршруту пройдёт запрос и что для этого необходимо?

Comment: *В каких случаях мы можем достоверно узнать по какому маршруту пройдёт запрос* Только в случае, когда все узлы маршрута находятся в области Вашего контроля или хотя бы в зоне известной политики администрирования. Иначе никаких гарантий.